# Is 'can' an appropriate substitute for 'may' to indicate possibility?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

One definition of *can* in Merriam-Webster Online is:

> c —used to indicate possibility < do you think he *can* still be alive> < those things *can* happen> ; sometimes used interchangeably with *may*

But in *The Elements of Style* written by William Strunk, Jr., it says:

> **Can**. Means *am (is, are) able*. Not to be used as a substitute for *may*.

This contradiction makes me confused. So in what situation can *can* be used "interchangeably" with *may*, and in what situation it cannot?

EDIT: The two sentences in *The Elements of Style* make me feel that the author permits only one use of *can* (be able) in the first sentence and proscribes the other use (*may*; to indicate possibility) in the second sentence. Did I misinterpret the author's meaning? Or the text is ambiguous?

Comment: There's a difference, maybe subtle, between *can* & *may* in the example sentences. With *can* you indicate a higher possibility while with *may* it's more like fifty-fifty.

Comment: The use of *can* in the example sentences does suggest a capability/ proclivity for the outcome unlike *may*, therefore it's **not** a substitute. As such, Strunk, Jr. is right.

Comment: @Kris But I think what Strunk Jr. means is that *can* can only be used in one meaning, that is "be able", and *may* is mentioned here to indicate its "possibility" meaning. My personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

They are not exactly the same. The wording in the dictionary entries are also somewhat different so they point to different aspects of the similarity and differences.

> sometimes used interchangeably with may

Means that in some cases they can be used for describing the same thing, but this depends on context, and possibly some re-phrasing needed to keep same meaning.

> Not to be used as a substitute for may.

Means that is not exactly the same, so you can not just switch the words in any context.

Comment: So do you mean that they are not contradictory? But the two sentences in _The Elements of Style_ make me feel that the author permits only one use of *can* (be able) in the first sentence and proscribes the other use (_may_; to indicate possibility) in the second sentence. Did I misinterpret the author's meaning? Or the text is ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

If you use *can* to ask for permission then *can* and *may* are the same thing.

If you use *can* to mean *be able* then they are not the same thing.

If you use *can* to mean *possibility* then *can* and *may* are the same thing.

> **Permission to fix something** *Can I fix this* can be replaced with *May I fix this*
>
> **Ability to fix something** *Can I fix this* cannot be replaced with *May I fix this*
>
> **Possibility to fix something** *Can I fix this* can be replaced with *May I fix this*

Whether you may use *can* to ask for permission can be argued about but I think *may* has been ousted as the main 'permission seeking' word by *can*.